Execution killed/timed out
I'm in a competition and when I'm solving this problem I get this error:
Execution killed (could be triggered by violating memory limits).
Basically I'm finding all the primes of a space[a,b] and then finding the biggest difference of 2 consecutive primes.
I understand why it's happening but I don't know how to optimize it even further.
Memory Limit: 256 MiB
code:
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a,b,div;
    cin>>a>>b;
    vector<int> v;
    vector<int> diff;
if(a%2==0){
    for (int i = a+1; i <= b; i+=2){
        div=0;
        for (int x = 1; x <=i; ++x){
            if(i%x==0)
                div++;
            }
        if(div==2) {
            v.push_back(i);
            }
        }
    if(v.size()>0) {
        for(int k=1; k<v.size(); ++k){
            int l=v.at(k)-v.at(k-1);
            diff.push_back(l);
            }
        for(int i=0; i<diff.size();++i) {
            if(diff.at(0)<diff.at(i)) {
                diff.at(0)=diff.at(i);
                }
            }
            cout<<diff.at(0);
        }
    else {
        cout<<0;
        }
    }
else {
    for (int i = a; i <= b; i+=2){
        div=0;
        for (int x = 1; x <=i; ++x){
            if(i%x==0)
                div++;
            }
        if(div==2) {
            v.push_back(i);
            }
        }
    if(v.size()>0) {
        for(int k=1; k<v.size(); ++k){
            int l=v.at(k)-v.at(k-1);
            diff.push_back(l);
            }
        for(int i=0; i<diff.size();++i) {
            if(diff.at(0)<diff.at(i)) {
                diff.at(0)=diff.at(i);
                }
            }
            cout<<diff.at(0);
        }
    else {
        cout<<0;
        }
    }
}


"I understand why it's happening": Please share.

Please edit your question as describe what the program is supposed to do and also what input you feed it.

Also, it would be good to know what are the memory limits.

You don't need diff; you can track the biggest difference as you go.

Either debug your code locally, or make sure you have the right algorithm. Whatever your problem is it isn't a C++ one (except for the bad readability of your code). It could well be the competition site is killing your code for taking to much time, there is no way for us to know

While using vector.at() is good while debugging, it includes range checks that could take up valuable time if you use a lot of them. Use plain indexing using the [] operator. Also, if you know the maximum size of the vectors, and it won't go over your memory limits, then you could reserve space for them which will make all your push_back calls more effective.

What exactly is your question?  Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, we don't simply work on other people's projects

Basically I'm finding all the primes of a space[a,b] -- Write a single function that just does that and only that.  -- and then finding the biggest difference of 2 consecutive primes -- Write a function that takes whatever is returned from the prime number function, and just finds the biggest difference.  Right now, your code is jumbled and jammed into a main function, using mostly single-letter variable names.  This makes the code hard(er) to understand and to even work with.

Here is a skeleton program that describes what I suggested.  That is a more coherent, easily debuggable, and easily understandable program.  You just need to fill the functions with the requisite code.  Not only that, you can isolate which function is causing the time limit issues.  All you need to do now is find either "better" code to get all primes between a range of numbers (maybe use the sieve approach?), and code to find the biggest gap between consecutive numbers (which should be relatively easy).
